# Changes in Controller not reflecting showing previous return value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

O make change in Controller but it is not effecting it is returning previous changed value not new.

I make many different kind but it is showing same first value which was returned.

I want to return new value from controller

```
//------------Logout--------------- 
public function logoutme() { 
    if (Session::has('RedPachUID')) { 
        Session::forget('RedPachUID'); 
        return "yes"; 
    } 
}
```

New Function

```
//------------Logout--------------- 
public function logoutme() { 
   if (Session::has('RedPachUID')) { 
       Session::forget('RedPachUID'); 
       return "No"; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet so we can see what's going on

Comment: but it is still retunring yes

Comment: You need to change your route to point to your new controller and your new controller method: `Route::any('/new/logout', 'YourNewController@logoutme')`

Answer (score 0):

it was happening because I was using  anchor tag when i used form to  logout it helps me

here is complete solution [logout function not invalidating session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277701/logout-function-not-invalidating-session/57277996#57277996)