# logout function not invalidating session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Basically problem is logout. But after spending whole day on it I came to know that session is working late. What i mean to say is that when I login and then try logout on first attempt it work fine. But on second attempt it is not working fine during this time request is not coming in controller but when I delete browser history it work perfect.On the other hand if difference between two attempts is 10  minutes then it work fine.

I don't know if it is server issue or laravel issue. But I tried all the things including composer commands.

I want to logout quickly on every attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salaam Bilal, try adding the following code in the view and render to see if it log outs. I'll explain this if it works.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/logout')}}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it is working but there is one more issue. when user switch from one account to another then it shows previous user data until refresh it. it is using ajax request to login

Comment: Man great... it works for me .. i spend my whole day on it..

please let me know why it happens

Comment: @BilalArshad Laravel has some security features built in which includes CSRF protection. For every input/data field in the application you have to add the CSRF input field for which you can write `{{ csrf_field() }}` or `@csrf` (if you are using blade templating). To make sure it's the logged in user logging out, you have to add the CSRF field in logout form.

Comment: I would suggest you go through the documentation and watch basics videos on youtube, they help a lot!!!! Cheers and All the best.